Getting Internal Server Error while calling Microsoft Graph Api Group
Getting error like internal server error while calling microsoft graph api.
I m trying to access group from azure.

Thanks
This Microsoft Graph should return Group from the azure. I m using Microsoft graph explorer only. I m singed in as well.

The same query works for me check this

Which account you signed in to Microsoft graph explorer?

Azure account only
I can access my
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
but getting issue with
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups

Is it Personal Microsoft account or work or school account?

earlier one was personal. but i changed to my work, but still it is not allowing me to singin . I share the issue in the latest comment on Answer

Assign Group administrator role to the user to fetch groups.

Note that: /groups endpoint doesn't support personal Microsoft account. Check this
Initially I got the same error when I signed in with personal Microsoft account:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups


Hence to resolve the error, you need to switch to a work or school account and log in to Microsoft Graph Explorer:
Now when I signed in with work or school account , I got the response successfully:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups



On Switch to work showing issue like
Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
AADSTS503241: Your administrator has configured the application Graph Explorer
('2131312312312423432') to block users unless they are specifically granted ('assigned') access to the application. The signed in user 'gmail.net' is blocked because they are not a direct member of a group with access, nor had access directly assigned by an administrator. Please contact your administrator to assign access to this application.

@SanjayPrasad Assign Group administrator role to the user to fetch groups

Rukmini and Naveen
No the issue is still there
You guys got anything?

What is the error you are facing?

Did you assign  active Group adminstrator role to the user

same as earlier

can you paste the screenshot of role assigned
